# How to use removePostDataItem with new jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

So i'm having a problem with upgrading to new jqGrid. Before i used 3.8.2 and i was using setPostDataItem and removePostDataItem, now those functions are depracated and i want to use new ones. So instead of setPostDataItem i found solution here: [jQuery jqGrid trigger reloadGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901587/jquery-jqgrid-trigger-reloadgrid).

But i couldn't found solution for removePostDataItem. I found that http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:upgrade_from_3.8_to_4.0.0, but i can't figure out what to write to actualy make it happen.

So what do i need to write instead of that?

```
$("#main_grid").removePostDataItem("user","admin");
```

Answer (score 1):

So i found a solution:

```
delete $("#main_grid").setGridParam({postData: "user"});
```

Jupi!